# Kernel32 not found when using FFmpeg.Autogen 4.1.0.2 in Mono/Linux

Tags: c#, dll, ffmpeg, mono, autogen

I'm submitting a bug report while I was posting this I didn't know I could see into FFmpeg.Autogen from the stacktrace. Anyways I posted a Bug Report on Github

## https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/issues/109

I'm trying to run my code in Linux that uses FFmpeg.Autogen to interface with the ffmpeg libraries. I am getting kernel32 dll not found can not figure out why. He says to not post issues to github for troubleshooting.
Possible related issue: https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/issues/89

First thing I've tried were to include the binary helper class from the example code I tweaked it a little bit. Added the exact path to the linux files.
Second thing I did was add FFmpeg.AutoGen.dll.config if configured right and it tries to ref a windows DLL it should point to the linux one.
Stacktrace:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: kernel32
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) FFmpeg.AutoGen.Native.WindowsNativeMethods.GetProcAddress(intptr,string)
  at FFmpeg.AutoGen.Native.FunctionLoader.GetFunctionPointer (System.IntPtr nativeLibraryHandle, System.String functionName) [0x00000] in D:\FFmpeg.AutoGen\FFmpeg.AutoGen\Native\FunctionLoader.cs:55
  at FFmpeg.AutoGen.Native.FunctionLoader.GetFunctionDelegate[T] (System.IntPtr nativeLibraryHandle, System.String functionName, System.Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in D:\FFmpeg.AutoGen\FFmpeg.AutoGen\Native\FunctionLoader.cs:28
  at FFmpeg.AutoGen.ffmpeg.GetFunctionDelegate[T] (System.IntPtr libraryHandle, System.String functionName) [0x00000] in D:\FFmpeg.AutoGen\FFmpeg.AutoGen\FFmpeg.cs:50
  at FFmpeg.AutoGen.ffmpeg+<>c.<.cctor>b__4_318 () [0x00000] in D:\FFmpeg.AutoGen\FFmpeg.AutoGen\FFmpeg.functions.export.g.cs:7163
  at FFmpeg.AutoGen.ffmpeg.avformat_alloc_context () [0x00000] in D:\FFmpeg.AutoGen\FFmpeg.AutoGen\FFmpeg.functions.export.g.cs:7176
  at FF8.FfccVaribleGroup..ctor () [0x0009c] in /home/robert/OpenVIII/FF8/FfccVaribleGroup.cs:53
  at FF8.Ffcc..ctor (System.String filename, FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVMediaType mediatype, FF8.Ffcc+FfccMode mode) [0x00008] in /home/robert/OpenVIII/FF8/Ffcc.cs:31
  at FF8.Module_movie_test.InitMovie () [0x00001] in /home/robert/OpenVIII/FF8/module_movie_test.cs:160
  at FF8.Module_movie_test.Update () [0x000c5] in /home/robert/OpenVIII/FF8/module_movie_test.cs:88
  at FF8.ModuleHandler.Update (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gameTime) [0x000ac] in /home/robert/OpenVIII/FF8/ModuleHandler.cs:43
  at FF8.Game1.Update (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gameTime) [0x00030] in /home/robert/OpenVIII/FF8/Game1.cs:69
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DoUpdate (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gameTime) [0x00019] in <4fc8466c27384bb19c7b81b2a6a71083>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Tick () [0x00103] in <4fc8466c27384bb19c7b81b2a6a71083>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.SdlGamePlatform.RunLoop () [0x00021] in <4fc8466c27384bb19c7b81b2a6a71083>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameRunBehavior runBehavior) [0x0008b] in <4fc8466c27384bb19c7b81b2a6a71083>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run () [0x0000c] in <4fc8466c27384bb19c7b81b2a6a71083>:0
  at FF8.Program.Main () [0x00007] in /home/robert/OpenVIII/FF8/Program.cs:17
```

My code that triggers this:

```
Format = ffmpeg.avformat_alloc_context();
```

Binaryhelper should set the path correctly for the file

```
internal static void RegisterFFmpegBinaries()
        {
            var libraryPath = "";
            switch (Environment.OSVersion.Platform)
            {
                case PlatformID.Win32NT:
                case PlatformID.Win32S:
                case PlatformID.Win32Windows:
                    var current = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                    var probe = Path.Combine(Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86");
                    while (current != null)
                    {
                        var ffmpegDirectory = Path.Combine(current, probe);
                        if (Directory.Exists(ffmpegDirectory))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"FFmpeg binaries found in: {ffmpegDirectory}");
                            RegisterLibrariesSearchPath(ffmpegDirectory);
                            return;
                        }
                        current = Directory.GetParent(current)?.FullName;
                    }
                    break;
                case PlatformID.Unix:
                    libraryPath = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu";
                    RegisterLibrariesSearchPath(libraryPath);
                    break;
                case PlatformID.MacOSX:
                    libraryPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(LD_LIBRARY_PATH);
                    RegisterLibrariesSearchPath(libraryPath);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The FFmpeg.Autogen.dll.config

```
<configuration>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="avutil-56.dll" target="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so.56"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="avcodec-58.dll" target="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.58"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="avformat-58.dll" target="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.58"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="avdevice-58.dll" target="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavdevice.so.58"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="avfilter-7.dll" target="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavfilter.so.7"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="avresample-4.dll" target="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavresample.so.4"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="swscale-5.dll" target="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale.so.5"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="swresample-3.dll" target="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample.so.3"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="postproc-55.dll" target="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpostproc.so.55"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Clearly the C# code tries to directly P/Invoke the GetProcAddress, which is a WinAPI method, requiring kernel32.dll - a Windows DLL...

Comment: I already see something I haven't spotted till now it's triggering off GetProcAddress Maybe this is a bug report. So it's not even the part trying to load the libraries?

Comment: Yes, it is not the part trying to load the libraries. It seems FFmpeg.Autogen has some hard-coded dependency/ies on the WinAPI. Best to check the issue tracker for FFmpeg.Autogen if the issue has already been reported, and if not, best to write a new issue report about the lacking Non-Windows compatibility.

Comment: Perhaps there is a platorm-neutral version of FFmpeg.Autogen available (in other words, a .NET standard port/build)? I don't know. According to the github frontpage of FFmpeg.Autogen, it should run in Linux. Are you perhaps using an old, outdated version that might not be Linux-compatible?

Comment: I think it's a NET45 issue that broke stuff in NET2 he has a switch case choosing which function to use. in NET45 he had it only using the windows function.

Comment: Well i just edited FFmpeg.Autogen's source and compiled it and the exception went away. though it's not "working" yet  Maybe there's more little issues Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/issues/109#issuecomment-477756443

Ruslan-B said he's going to fix it.

After applying a fix it's mostly working I figure I'm only not seeing video because the colorspace i'm using is wrong for linux that's my guess. Audio is working fine.

But this issue is closed.

Elgonzo in comments helped point out the correct issue was not the libraries failing to load. And that it is that FFmpeg.Autogen is using the wrong windows-only function.

Comment: I figured out why it wasn't drawing the video in the question below. So everything is working now. And the fix has been applied to FFmpeg.Autogen.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437187/is-there-another-way-to-export-a-frame-in-ffmpeg-to-a-texture2d-my-code-working